# SQL, website and desktop application on a Windows Azure server?

Tags: virtual-machines, sql, website, azure

I recently started considering Azure over my current VPS host PhotonVPS for Virtual Machines. I assume that Virtual Machines are the same as VPS servers (please correct me if I am wrong about that).

Now, I need a server running a desktop program which also has a website on it and an SQL server.

I assume that all of these will be able to run just fine in a virtual machine from Azure, but I am worried about pricing.

I have looked at the available options and prices, and it seems that it is possible to also host the website and SQL server separately instead of just installing it on the virtual machine.

What would be the pros and cons of that versus running it all on the same virtual machine in terms of cost and performance? Is it generally considered a bad idea to run my website and my SQL on a virtual machine as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points to consider:

- Pricing is significantly different between Web Site and SQL VM
- Web sites are pretty easy to scale, while VMs might require more efforts to achieve scale out
- Separating web and DB layers makes resources and security management easier